# How do I set notifications for my questions?

Tags: support, notifications

I want to receive an email whenever someone answers or comments on one of my questions. How can  I do that? I can't find anything like that in my user account.

Answer (score 2):

Recently the email settings button was removed from the supercolider tm. Email settings are now located in the user preferences:

[image]

And of course you get bugged each time you ask a question and you're not subscribed (as already described by @Lucifer):

[image]

Comment: Hi m0sa, I set up all mail notifications in my profile, but I continue to not receive anything in my email.....

Comment: @Luca you only receive email notifications when you don't view them on a se site for that period. If you want push notifications for everything I stongly recommend using one of our mobile apps

Comment: I'm sorry but it does not seem that is what you're saying. In last days effectively, I'm on SO everydays, but in past weeks and months it will happen that I was away for days. In addiction, I set "boundary notification time" on three hours, so I expect that someone answer a my question during night, next morning I should have an email in my inbox, because of my last visit on SO was more than 3 hours before....

Comment: @Luca I checked your history, you only enabled the "Email me my unread inbox items" option 2 hours ago. It was disabled before (since Jul 12th 2013), so no wonder you haven't received any inbox notifications in the past.

Comment: Nope... is not correct. That option was already enabled for months (at least... it was "visually" checked); 2 hours ago I enabled only "Email chat event reminders... etc etc"

Comment: Here the confirmation of my feelings. Yesterday night I asked a question on SO and answered another one. This morning, after 10 hours, I can see 2 replies notified inside SO website, but in my email did not arrive anything, even if I set "3 hours" threshold and obviously... I did not check SO during past 10 hours.... :-(

Comment: @LucaDetomi you should be receiving inbox notification emails, the systems sends them out for sure. Have you checked all folders in your email inbox (including spam?)

Comment: Unfortunately..... nothing in spam too.....

Answer (score 0):

For each the question you asked, there is a email link after the last answer.

> Would you like to have responses to your questions **sent to you via email?**

Click on the "sent to you via email" and you will get notification via email.

Comment: But in the profile of this forum, dont exist some kind of notification?

Answer (score 0):

Click the stackexchange dropdown at the top left of the page, and pick "email settings".

Answer (score 0):

Install this awesome Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/desktop-notifications-for/ijglncoabcgieiokjmgdogpefdblmnle